# getting Duplicate List Values in GET API service in spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

i am getiing proper values from DB but Getting Duplicate List Values while add list object to class object, in Spring Boot
Please suggest to me how to do it.

**Get data from DB Code : Here Rooms is my DB Entity class**

```
CriteriaBuilder roomsBuilder = roomSession.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Rooms> query = roomsBuilder.createQuery(Rooms.class);
Root<Rooms> root = query.from(Rooms.class);
Predicate userRestriction = roomsBuilder.or(roomsBuilder.notEqual(root.get(SmatrEntityParameters.IS_DELETED), "Y"),
                roomsBuilder.isNull(root.get(SmatrEntityParameters.IS_DELETED)));
Predicate userRestriction2 = roomsBuilder.and(roomsBuilder.equal(root.join("properties").get(SmatrEntityParameters.PROPERTY_ID), propertyId));
query.where(roomsBuilder.and(userRestriction, userRestriction2));
Query q = roomSession.createQuery(query);
List<Rooms> getroomslistobj= q.getResultList();
```

**Iterate the list code: Here getAllRoomsobj means main response pojo class**

```
List<GetAllRooms> getallroomslistobj = new ArrayList<GetAllRooms>();
    for (int i = 0; i < getroomslistobj.size(); i++) {    
                        int dbroomId = getroomslistobj.get(i).getRoomId();
                        String dbroomName = getroomslistobj.get(i).getRoomName();
              // Actual code start
                        getAllRoomsobj.setRoomId(dbroomId);
                        getAllRoomsobj.setRoomName(dbroomName);
                        getallroomslistobj.add(getAllRoomsobj);
    
             // Actual code end
    }
```

**I tried one code at the middle of the Actual code but I did not want create a new object for the response class:**

```
GetAllRooms object = new GetAllRooms();
                object.setRoomId(dbroomId);
                object.setRoomName(dbroomName);
                getallroomslistobj.add(object);
```

Please Help me Out,

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why you don't want to create new object? How would objects in List would differ then? Your question is not completely clear

Comment: If we have 100loops in for, then here 100 objects will create so... That's way

Comment: I think you are thinking too much about performance here, you would have to create 100 objects if you want to send list of 100 objects, you cannot do this way, here, you are adding multiple references of same object into list and in each iteration updating it, will update all others because object in memory is same. So there are multiple references but same object at each index in list.

Answer (score -1):

u  can try it by stream.map() of java8

Comment: can you explain me with an example